World Building Knowledgebase - How to write good Military World Building
Firstly - for the Mods - I am not sure if this is the right place to put this, but I couldn't find anywhere else for it - essentially, there are a lot of questions around Military/Weapons/Warfare that are often missing the same considerations - so in the hopes of providing a Meta-Answer for prospective World Builders on how to build a good Military or weapon or similar item - I am writing this post.
TheDemonLords Tips for writing good Military World Building number 1 - Work backwards
What do I mean by this? Well - before you get to designing your new fancy-pants cool weapon for your awesome world that you are creating - stop and ask yourself:
What is the function that this Military entity is created to address?
You might roll your eyes and go 'Duh to fight wars!' - but you would be hopelessly wrong. To use real world examples - Different Militaries have different goals in existence. Sweden and Switzerland for example are famous for their neutrality - consequently their Militaries are designed around defence of the homeland, in Swedens case - in the 20th century, this was specifically around defending against Russian aggression. This lead to things like the S-Tank - which was a response to the threat that large numbers of Russian armour would roll into Sweden - so a low-profile turretless tank that could ambush, move, reconceal and repeat where they were not expected to have numerical superiority was the order of the day.
The NZDF on the other-hand has a lot of experience with humanitarian missions in the Pacific islands.
Then you have the countries with Blue-water navies, the US being the best example where the primary goal of their military is to project power - to be the big stick that keeps everyone in line.
Let us consider a World Building example - you are inventing a new military force for story and world building reasons - let us even throw in that there is something unique you want them to be doing (Clone troops, Power Armour, AI weapons, Alien races - whatever) - and like all World Builders you are excited about getting into the detail of your cool new force... (we have all been there) But you are struggling to make them seem real - well, first and foremost is probably because you haven't thought about the adversary or roll that your force is expected to counter or fulfill.
It doesnt make a lot of sense to have a military that is filled with heavy tanks with mega-armour, if they are going to be fighting against a few uncivilized tribes with bows and arrows, likewise if you want a military that is made up of super-ninjas who slash and stab - having them pitted against Cyborgs with hardened exo-amour also doesnt make a lot of sense.
First - think about what you want your military to do

Peacekeeping military
Homeland defense militia
Asymetric warfare terrorists or rebels
De-facto police force
Global super-power/world police
Island nation or Xenophobia
Sphere of influence around unstable neighbours
Humanitarian force

The list goes on - the point is this - the first step to make your military feel realistic is to have it be a reasonable response to the perceived mission it is seeking to fulfill.
TheDemonLords Tips for writing good Military World Building Number 2 - What is the philosophy(s) of the country or region
The easiest way to highlight this is comparing the likes of the US Military with say the Imperial Japanese Airforce or ISIS fighters.
The US places a high premium on the lives of their Service Members - one of their Credo is No man left behind. This means that they will often risk elite tier units and operators to rescue wounded soldiers.
Conversely - on the other side of the spectrum, countries have repeatedly used suicide attacks (ISIS and Kamikaze pilots respectively)
In addition to this - you have things like how the Military is structured - a military that is under control of a Democratically elected government with a free press is much more likely to be more... Restrained when it comes to the excesses of War, whereas a Military force that believes the Enemy to be infidels or untermensch or any other dehumanized group is going to be a lot more War-crime happy
As a general rule - Militaries that tend-towards valuing human life will opt for more precision weaponary, better body-armour, better medical evac support, limited effects on target (so things like poison rounds)
Whereas Militaries that have less accountability to the people or a belief in the inferiority of the enemy are more likely to have area-of-effect weapons, Excessively injurious weapons, Conscript troops with little or no training etc.
This is not a hard and fast rule - for example a Military that believes in Racial Superiority might have a callous outlook on their own service members (We dont need body amour - we are the choosen people!) or they might have a protective outlook on their own service members (Each drop of pure blood is precious and should not be wasted!)
TheDemonLords Tips for writing good Military World Building number 3 - Everything is a Compromise
In the real world - even the most Overpowered bit of Military gear has numerous compromises that are a result of desired role.
Consider the .223 NATO round that is used in most infantry rifles. It is a good round that can accurately and effectively engage a Man-sized target within 400 metres. It has light recoil and good terminal ballistics. It is the product of the realization that most infantry-on-infantry engagements in WW2 took place within 400 metres (which is about the distance that you can identify someone without optics).
There are many rounds that have greater range, greater stopping power, terminal ballistics etc. but they all have their trade-offs, Greater range generally means a bigger cartridge which means for a given weight, the soldier in the field can carry less ammo. Greater stopping power generally means a heavier bullet which increases recoil making full-auto uncontrollable.
This is not limited to Rounds - Aircraft, Ships, Tanks, Subs - everything has a trade-off. Less Amour means more agility, better stealth means less fuel efficient, Larger fighting compartment means bigger target etc. etc.
In the real world - weapon designers consider how and where the system is likely to be used and then make the compromises based on that. A Main Battle Tank (MBT) is going to be in a position where it is attracting an awful lot of attention, so it needs to be heavily armoured to take the hits and keep fighting. Whereas a Scout vehicle needs only to be able to outrun anything it can't fight - and often will have a light anti-armour missile or similar system to give anything that it can't outfight a bloody nose so as to think twice.
Sometimes it is the right call to have a less impressive bang, for a more practical bang.
Also - an addendum to this rule - this is also why Super-Weapons tend to suck both in World Building and in real life.
TheDemonLords Tips for writing good Military World Building number 4 - The Human Factor - or who is doing your fighting
I am going to say Human for the sake of brevity - but regardless of what is doing your fighting - there are limitations - Endurance, Carrying Capacity, Logistics etc. Even in the modern military with mechanised infill and exfil - there is still a need for a Soldier to carry supplies in and out of the battlefield. Even if you have an all Robot army - they still need power - the point is the individual soldier or fighting unit has needs:
What are they and then the follow-up: How does addressing these needs impact their equipment.
You want all of your soldiers to be armed with massive super-assault-rifles - Thats cool... How does that look when you have been stuck in the middle of a Jungle or Dessert or other horrible place for a week because your supply shipment was intercepted.
Think about the limitations of the individual soldier and then think how a Military might work around these or compromise on these.
TheDemonLords Tips for writing good Military World Building number 5 - It is rarely overkill, it is usually good enough
So this is kind of an amalgamation of all the above points to talk about something we see often here - which is specifically about designing Weapons. Often people will want really cool sounding Fusion-plasmo-blaster 9000s for their standard infantry weapon that can do everything from stun a person to nuke the sun...
THIS IS A BAD WEAPONS SYSTEM
In the real world - whilst we have some very destructive weapons systems, generally we try to have it be just lethal enough to get the job done. As above with compromise - adding capability always comes at a cost. Having your standard infantry rifle being effective against tanks is cool and all, but that capability will come at a cost - and 9 times out of 10 it probably isnt worth it - it is probably more worth it scaling down the power or cost or size or weight or any N number of things that would make this capability feasible to make it a better weapon.
Now - if your world building has a guerrila force fighting against an all-mechanized force, then it makes more sense if the likely thing you are going to be fighting is tanks, then this makes sense - but most of the time - Militaries will want something that is only just good enough to get the job done - and so limiting the capabilities of your weapons system to make it effective against the most likely target leads to a more immersive world.
To everyone who reads this - if you have other good Meta-suggestions on what makes for a good bit of military world building - please add answers or comments and I would love to include these with appropriate credit and citations

1.  Wouldn't point 1 be working forwards? If you don't have a military, but want one, you'd need to look forwards to determine scope. If you've already got a military and want to fix it, working backwards to see what it's already doing might make sense.

2.  I'm looking at the order of the points. Might the underlying philosophy of the country be a better starting point than what the military is going to be for? Knowing this first would help guide the worldbuilder when it comes to the other points. It seems that points 3, 4, and 5 kind of address the same thing: systems design.

3.  Perhaps these could be condensed into one point with primary focus on systems design & logistics considerations with secondary focus on what are essentially anecdotal bits of wisdom: compromise vs overdesign. So: Point 1 -- National Philosophy; Point 2 -- Purpose and Function; Point 3 -- Systems Design.  I think the actual verbiage seems okay!

@elemtilas - I can re-arrange if needed - I see your point about working forwards - most WB (IMO) tend to come up with the cool flashy sounding idea - and then struggle to make it work in their world - so for them, it is working backwards - e.g. I want the Starkiller-8,000 how do I justify it. I will wait a little for more feedback, then re-jig as needed.

Okay, I see what you mean by working backwards now! I guess that would fall under retconning. I do like how you begin from first principles: basic philosophies, basic functions, basic systems and weapons. You're providing a good foundation for exactly that scenario! Ultimately, I believe the goal would not so much be to dissuade worldbuilders from the Starkiller 8000, but rather to consider its ramifications and how to get to that point?

@elemtilas - Yeah, I love an awesome sounding super-weapon as much as the next guy - I also want it to work within a believable world.

This should be in Q&A format like the rest of the site. The question being "How to write good Military World Building" and the answer...well answering that question.

I love the idea, just pessimistic that people will read it before posting. The "what is the purpose of this military force" should definitely stay first, IMO, it is the most glaring omission in many questions which sets up unreasonable expectations. Consider putting something about procurement and logistics in point 5 - there's a wonderful passage in Old Mans War where a new recruit makes a comment about it being unfair on the aliens how well equipped the CDF is and gets literally smacked down by the sergeant saying that their super-rifles are the minimum to give the CDF a fighting chance.

@KerrAvon2055 - hahaha - yes, I am an eternal Optimist :D - Good point on procurement and Logistics - I might think on that and update

From experience, I know that Meta is a terrible place for stuff like this. Only a tiny fraction of the whole visit Meta and the post will soon be lost to the dunes of SE time. I'd recommend you do something like this where you post a question that explains what you're trying to achieve and then post what you have above as a Community Wiki answer. More people will remember it and when you link to it in comments, it's listed on the side bar where (as I recall) Meta Qs are not.

@JBH - Good point, I will look into doing that later on.

Please do it. Armies come into being for a purpose and the purpose is never fighting wars. Fighting wars is always to be avoided whenever there is another way to achieve the real goals. War is something which is only done for a purpose, and no sane country would choose war as a path to fulfill their purpose unless they are forced to or cannot think of any better way.

Cheers. Also, when you're ready, be sure to link this appropriately into the list of worldbuilding resources. That will help if you plan to keep it here, but it'll be better all the way around to push this out to Main.
